# Text* Validation - Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, forms, validation, field, contact-form-7

Good morning,

I have implemented a simple form with First Name, Last Name, Phone, Mail, 2 acceptance checkboxes and a field for uploading pdf files.

The form behaves that as long as the first mandatory checkbox is not ticked, the button cannot be clicked and the check on the fields is not done.

The problem is that a check is made on the Phone field (only accepting numbers), a check is made on the email but no check is made on the first and last name fields.

Is it possible to run a check on the two fields, a simple true/false if it is filled in?

I enclose the form code below:

```
[text* Nome "Nome *"]
[text* Cognome "Cognome *"]
[tel* phone "Telefono *"]
[email* mail "Email *"]
<br>
[acceptance Trattamentodati "Acconsento al trattamento dei miei dati personali ai sensi dell'articolo 13 del Regolamento (UE) 2016/679 *"]
[acceptance Trattamentocommerciale optional "Acconsento al trattamento dei dati per comunicazioni commerciali e informative su Eventi, Prodotti e Servizi"]
<br>
<label> Carica il tuo CV (in formato PDF - max 1MB)
    [file* FileCV limit:1mb filetypes:pdf] </label>
<br>
[submit "Invia il Curriculum"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by rewriting the contact form code like this:

```
[text* Nome placeholder "Nome *"] 
[text* Cognome placeholder "Cognome *"]
[tel* phone placeholder "Telefono *"] 
[email* mail placeholder "Email *"]
<br>
[acceptance Trattamentodati] Acconsento al trattamento dei miei dati personali ai sensi dell'articolo 13 del Regolamento (UE) 2016/679 * [/acceptance]
[acceptance Trattamentocommerciale optional] Acconsento al trattamento dei dati per comunicazioni commerciali e informative su Eventi, Prodotti e Servizi [/acceptance]
<br>
<label> Carica il tuo CV (in formato PDF - max 1MB)
    [file* FileCV limit:1mb filetypes:pdf] </label>
<br>
[submit "Invia il Curriculum"]
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [CF7 documentation](https://contactform7.com/acceptance-checkbox/): unlike other form-tag types, the `[acceptance]` tag has a closing tag `[/acceptance]` at the tail.

You should use it like so:

```
[acceptance your-consent] I consent to the conditions. [/acceptance]
```

This should work for your form:

```
[acceptance Trattamentodati] Acconsento al trattamento dei miei dati personali ai sensi dell'articolo 13 del Regolamento (UE) 2016/679 * [/acceptance]
[acceptance Trattamentocommerciale optional] Acconsento al trattamento dei dati per comunicazioni commerciali e informative su Eventi, Prodotti e Servizi [/acceptance]
```